# rc.local load on startup on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, boot

i have an script to do someting  and it's work well but 
I want to put this script in my rc.local because every time that my linux reboot it start in startup

i did in my rc.local but it's not work

```
nano rc.local 

/root/myscript &
```

I try like this

```
nano rc.local 
/root/myscript
```

and again it's not working for me . script is ok and every time I run script like this , it work

```
cd root/
./myscript
```

plz help

Comment: Where is `rc.local` located?

Comment: in linux . /etc/rc.local

Answer (score -1):

`rc.local` should come out of the box, so if you're using `nano` and an empty file pops-up, you're doing something wrong (likely in wrong directory) and you're creating a new file that the OS is not gonna pick up automatically.

If you run `cat -n /etc/rc.local` in Ubuntu, for example, you get this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

To my knowledge, and according this [article](https://blog.hostonnet.com/centos-7-rc-local-not-working), `rc.local` in centOS is located in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, so try running this command instead:

`nano /etc/rc.d/rc.local`